# Converting a negative number in oracle to Hexadecimal is giving wrong output?

Tags: oracle, plsql, hex, to-char

I am using below select statement to convert a positive number to hexadecimal

```
SQL>select to_char('2122699925', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') from testable
Output : 7E85D495
```

But the TO_CHAR for negative number it is giving me output as `#################`

```
SQL>select to_char('-2122699925', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') from testable
Output : #################
```

The required output should be 817A2B6B. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation says (**Table 2-13 Number Format Elements**), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

> Returns the hexadecimal value of the specified number of digits. If the specified number is not an integer, then Oracle Database rounds it to an integer.

> Restrictions:

> This element accepts only positive values or 0. Negative values return an error.

.......

However I was able to find the below link which does the conversation for negative numbers. I had no intention to copy it but providing you the link if it helps you in any way,

[Conversion of negative numbers to hexadecimal](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/152170/2/)

Comment: Hello Sujitmohanty, the post was helpful and did solve my question but what does number 4294967296 represents in the below statement?

<pre>
 1  SELECT val,
  2           To_Char(
  3            Decode(
  4               Sign(val), -1 , 4294967296  - Abs(val),
  5                               Abs(val)
  6           ), 'XXXXXXXX') FROM
  7*   (SELECT -1000175007 val FROM dual)
</pre>

Comment: Its nothing but POWER(16,8) . As I understood from the post depends on the number we  want to convert to HEX i.e. `16` represents the hexadecimal and `8` depends .on what kind of hexadecimal we want to convert 2 digit hex or 3 digit hex or 8 digit hex and so on.. There is some gap in understanding for me though with the alternative approach.